# Sejda Console Error Invalid Value for Location of File

Tags: pdf, sejda

This is my batch file but I am getting the following error:
sejda-console splitdownthemiddle -f C:\Users\rigo\Test.pdf C:\Users\rigo\Split.pdf -o C:\Users\rigo\
exit

Invalid value  does not exit. The file is in the correct location though.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Windows 7 Prof 64. Using Sejda Console 2.0.0.M14

Comment: Seems your post is missing the part with the error you are getting?

Comment: Maybe the output directory?.. it seems there's a space before the last exit subfolder